# Nginx socket() failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol) and push stream failed

Tags: networking, server, nginx, streaming, ipv6

I use nginx with the rtmp module and I use push to send the rtmp stream to my stream server. I don't send the stream directly to the stream server because I first check if the stream key is the right one with on_publish.

My structure : OBS -> nginx -> Stream server

I have to start the stream twice with OBS because this error always occurs every other time and I don't know why :

```
2020/07/18 16:38:05 [alert] 9749#9749: socket() failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)
2020/07/18 16:38:05 [error] 9749#9749: *1 relay: push failed name='channel_53865575q25_jSbmKzKP926NvBMn54oDeW66Mp7QhFLWn6Phbx2IJPckX0fTV5' app='' playpath='' url='127.0.0.1:1936/app/$name' args='', client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:1935
```

I tried to enable and disable ipv6 in the "default" configuration file of nginx, I have replaced all "localhost" by "127.0.01" on nginx.conf to force ipv4 and I also tried to comment "::1" in the /etc/hosts file, but nothing worked, this error always appears once out of two times. Can someone give me some advice?

Regards,
Mateo